# CFWheels Nested Properties and hasManyCheckBox

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels, nested-properties

I am trying to figure out how can I update the petevents table with several events. I get no error, but it is also not updating/inserting. Here are the relevant code snippets and the schema for the relevant tables follows.

**View**

```
<cfloop query="events">

#hasManyCheckBox(objectName="pet",

association="petevents",

keys="#pet.key()#,#events.id#",

label=events.eventname)#

</cfloop>
```

**Pet Model**

```
<cfset hasMany(name="petEvents", dependent="deleteAll", shortcut="events")>
<!--- nested properties --->
<cfset nestedProperties(associations="petEvents", allowDelete=true)>
```

**Event Model**

```
<cfset hasMany(name="petevents", dependent="deleteAll")>
```

**PetEvent Model**

```
<cfset belongsTo("pet")>    
<cfset belongsTo(name="event", joinType="outer")>
```

**View Update in Controller**

```
<cfset pet = model("pet").findByKey(key=params.key)>
<cfset pet.update(params.pet)>
```

[image: Schema pertaining to relevant tables]

EDIT: I change the validatesPresenceOf property "when" to oncreate only. Then I saved and got this error. "Duplicate entry '1025-1025' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Thanks,

Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, don't forget to include `petEvents`:

```
<cfset pet = model("pet").findByKey(key=params.key, include="petEvents")>
```

EDIT:

In response to your dump below, can you tell me what you get when you do this in your update action?

```
<cfset pet = model("pet").findByKey(key=params.key, include="petEvents")>
<cfset pet.setProperties(params.pet)>
<cfdump var="#pet#" abort>
```

If that appears to be fine, what happens when you do this? Any errors?

```
<cfset pet = model("pet").findByKey(key=params.key, include="petEvents")>
<cfset pet.setProperties(params.pet)>
<cfset pet.update()>
<cfdump var="#pet.allErrors()#">
<cfloop array="#pet.petEvents#" index="petEvent">
    <cfdump var="#petEvent.allErrors()#">
<cfloop>
<cfabort>
```

Comment: I was really hoping this would work, but alas, it does not save my checkboxes still.

Comment: Here is the dump of params when trying to update
![CF Dump](http://i369.photobucket.com/albums/oo140/dbinnc/3-28-201211-33-18AM.png)

Comment: See my questions in the EDIT above.

Comment: here is the output of the first question
![Output #1](http://i369.photobucket.com/albums/oo140/dbinnc/3-29-201211-12-33AM.png)

and yes, I am getting an error "Please provide a value for pet type", but there is no such form field. And I thought I was not making it check when I did this update.

Comment: I just looked at that first output, the petid and eventid in petEvents are reversed. where is that set?

Comment: i found it. was in the hasmanycheckbox keys attribute. just reversed it. Thanks Chris!